# Flex item fill height but without flex-direction: column

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

## What I have so far

This is the flex layout I have. It is based on the idea of holy-grail.
[This is what current layout look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GooN5.png)

## What I'm trying to do

I need `main` to stretch to fill remaining height
[This is what I'm trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ovic.png)

Most solutions I found on the internet won't work for me.
So far my attempts with %based heights have nothing fruitful.
Setting main height to 100% will make it overflow parent container.
Headers and footer don't have fixed height, hence, `calc` based solutions also won't work.

---

External Links:

current_layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GooN5.png
trying layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ovic.png

## Code snippet

```css
.ctm .grail {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: space-between;

    gap: var(--ctm-gap, 1em) var(--ctm-gap, 1em);
}

.ctm .grail>details,
.ctm .grail>header,
.ctm .grail>nav,
.ctm .grail>footer {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.ctm .grail>header {
    min-height: 4em;
}

.ctm .grail>main {
    flex-grow: 3;
}

.ctm .grail>aside {
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: min(6em, 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="ctm">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Consortium Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/output/web/styles.css">

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            min-height: 100vh;
            background-color: #122334;
        }

        details {
            background-color: #f00;
            color: #fff;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #f44;
            color: #fff;
        }

        nav {
            background-color: #0f0;
            color: #fff;
        }

        aside {
            background-color: #00f;
            color: #fff;
        }

        main {
            background-color: #ff0;
            color: #000;
        }

        footer {
            background-color: #f0f;
            color: #fff;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body class="grail">
    <details>
        <summary>Notification</summary>
        <p>Details</p>
    </details>
    <header>Header</header>
    <nav>Navigation</nav>
    <aside>Left</aside>
    <main>Main</main>
    <aside>Right</aside>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure of HTML needs to be change to get the required output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="ctm">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Consortium Test</title>


    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: #122334;
      }

      details {
        background-color: #f00;
        color: #fff;
      }

      header {
        background-color: #f44;
        color: #fff;
      }

      nav {
        background-color: #0f0;
        color: #fff;
      }

      aside {
        background-color: #00f;
        color: #fff;
      }

      main {
        background-color: #ff0;
        color: #000;
      }

      footer {
        background-color: #f0f;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .ctm .grail {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-content: space-between;

        gap: var(--ctm-gap, 1em) var(--ctm-gap, 1em);
      }

      .ctm .grail > details,
      .ctm .grail > header,
      .ctm .grail > nav,
      .ctm .grail > footer {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .ctm .grail > header {
        min-height: 4em;
      }

      .body main {
        flex-grow: 2;
      }

      /* .ctm .grail   */
      .body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex: 1;
        gap: 16px;
        /* wid */
      }
      .body aside {
        flex-grow: 1;
        min-width: min(6em, 100%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="grail">
    <details>
      <summary>Notification</summary>
      <p>Details</p>
    </details>
    <header>Header</header>
    <nav>Navigation</nav>
    <div class="body">
      <aside>Left</aside>
      <main>Main</main>
      <aside>Right</aside>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agreed. But I need everything directly inside the root element. Aren't there any work arounds to this?

Comment: @DwijBavisi Since the parent is flex and flex-direction is a column all the elements will be one below the other. 
If you want everything directly in root element, then you can try without flex

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `vh` based heights?

Having set the height of all the elements apart from `main` would be really helpful, as it allows to use `calc()`.

Other than that, here is my solution for your problem:https://codepen.io/SwampWitch/pen/eYjrmNa?editors=1100

I wrapped `main` and `aside` in a `div`, then used `display: flex` on it, along with eyeballed value of `height: 80vh`. Using `calc()` would be much more elegant solution and a responsive one at that.

Comment: why to add height 80vh? since parent is display flex, div can be flex: 1

Comment: OP wanted to give it a height, and declaring flex: 1 doesn't do it. Maybe there is a better way to achieve the same effect that I'm missing.